# WearOS - Fossil Gen5 Daily Steps and Heart Rate on Watch face

Tags: wear-os, google-fit, google-fit-api

I'm making my own watch face but can't find any working method to get my heart rate and daily steps. Preferably I'd get those from Google Fit API, have already tried al their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/overview), nothing worked so far. Does anyone have any experience with this?

This is my project so far: https://github.com/XDoubleU/watchface

Comment: The easiest way to get daily steps is as a complication - and if you're on a Fossil watch, there's a heart rate complication too. [You sort of imply that you're just making this watch face for your own use?]

Comment: @String is it also possible to get the data from these complications and just get the steps and heart rate as integer?